# List of unordered sets of coordinates

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stl

*I'm trying to make a list of unordered sets of coordinates, as main model for a game of life. As so, I am trying to make the following code work :*

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <list>

struct coords {int x; int y;};
std::list<std::unordered_set<coords>> data;
```

---

This code leads to many, many errors (Thanks C++....) like the ones that follow :

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<coords>) (const coords&)’
error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<coords> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<coords, std::hash<coords> > >’
error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<coords> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<coords, std::hash<coords> > > >’

and so on, and so forth.
```

**Where do these errors come from, and more importantly, how could I have figured that out by myself, as those errors look totally unreadable ?**

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Btw, you need not repeat the `struct` keyword in C++.

Comment: using the following CMakeLists.txt : `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11);
project(GOL_controller CXX); add_library(GOL SHARED src/main.cpp);`

Comment: @BaummitAugen I know, it came here from me trying to solve the problem ^_^ thanks anyway

Comment: *"how could I have figured that out by myself, as those errors look totally unreadable?"* In this particular case, I googled *"c++ unordered_set of custom type"*. But I agree, many error messages in C++ are terrible, such as this one. That's one of the main motivations of the Concepts TS, in hopes of getting an error along the lines of  "Type `coords` must be hashable" in the future.

Comment: Wow, awesome TS ! hope it will get included in the next C++ version :3

Comment: @Magix It won't be in C++17 unfortunately, as it turned out to be not good enough yet. The error messages were much more verbose and unclear than intended. They try to get an improved version into C++20, let's hope for the best. It turns out standardizing C++ is hard. :)